# Is there any advantage of running EMT over FMC?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I was planning to extend the existing FMC conduit that runs my Dryer circuit with two additional 20A circuits for bathroom and washing machine (both of which are currently hanging on some random circuits).

[Confirmed that everything works](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274609/dryer-laundry-bathroom-in-3-4-flex-fmc) but frustratingly turns out the previous conduit was not 3/4" but just 1/2". So I need to replace parts of the 1/2" FMC with 3/4" FMC. It's in the basement, so somewhat "easily" accessible.

Now that I have to redo things anyway, is there any reason I should pick EMT instead?

Except for price and usage as grounding conductor, I can only think of disadvantages: Very labor intensive to install, many small parts required (couplers), need to rent/purchase a bender etc.

Comment: Pretty sure my pair of used (they are a simple tool that lasts and lasts) benders have paid for themselves many times over by now, but that may not apply to you.